# makeEwsRequestAsync randomly generates error

Tags: outlook, office-js

I'm using Office JavaScript API to edit and save emails through an Add-in.
To get all attachments of an email, I use [`makeEwsRequestAsync`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office.context.mailbox?product=outlook&version=v1.5). Most of the time the method is successful but sometimes it returns this error:

> Failed to make a request via `HttpWebRequest`. 
>   Exception: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

```json
{
    "value": null,
    "status": "failed",
    "error": {
        "name": "GenericResponseError",
        "message": "Failed to make a request via `HttpWebRequest`. Exception: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.",
        "code ": 9020
    }
}
```

I'm working with Outlook 2016 Online (Office 365 ProPlus Version 1711) and I got the error on Windows 10 machine using both Chrome and Edge browsers.

**EDIT:**

Here is the full scenario:

1. Create new email
2. Hit send button
3. Add-in will intercept send event
4. Add-in saves email under draft using `Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync` that will return `itemId`
5. Once `itemId` is returned, try to load email headers and attachments (in parallel) by calling two `makeEwsRequestAsync` methods (using `itemId` with properly formated XML)

I can only think about 3 issues:

- Is it possible that `saveAsync` returns an `itemId` that does not exist yet?
  But in this case, I'm expecting a different error message.
- Does calling 2 `makeEwsRequestAsync` simultaneously is problematic?
  I don't think so. JavaScript is single threaded and the 2 methods are never called at the same time.
- Is there a session timeout to communicate with EWS API?

Also, The error happens in different mailboxes and there is no other prior or post error.

Comment: Can you clarify if you using Outlook Online or/and Outlook 2016 for Windows? Also, an example of the code you're using would be helpful.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur I'm using Outlook  Online

Comment: Are you getting any other messages before or after this? Is there anything else you can describe about the scenario? Is this with any mailbox? Only some mailboxes? What just of request are you making? There isn't much to go on at the moment.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur I edited my question with full scenario and some thoughts. Thanks

Comment: To clarify on Outlook online, is the mailbox an Office365 account? Do you have an estimate on the error rate.

Comment: Also, to comment on your 3 thoughts, 1. for Outlook online, getting an itemid for a non existent item should not be possible, since the item is saved on the server before an itemid is returned. 2. the 2 makeEwsRequestAsync can be simultaneous, while JavaScript is single threaded, the 2 calls can arrive at Exchange at almost the same time. Are you making GetItem and GetAttachment in your 2 EWS calls? When failure happens, is there a pattern (both calls fail, attachment call fails, etc)?  3. EWS can time out, does the failure only happen after a long wait?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT mailbox is an Office365 account. Error rate is about 1/20

Comment: Do you have information about the other comments?  Are you making GetItem and GetAttachment in your 2 EWS calls? When failure happens, is there a pattern (both calls fail, attachment call fails, etc)? 3. EWS can time out, does the failure only happen after a long wait?